# How to Resolve More than One Column with same Name in Data Source?

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008 to extract data from SQL Server, grab fields from other databases along the way, do a derived column to convert strings and a data conversion transform before storing the output to a text file.

Somehow along the way, the EncounterNumber field is being duplicated.  The output columns metadata from the data conversion transform to the flat file destination shows this field twice.  The error I'm getting when trying to map fields into the flat is as follows:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [Flat File Destination [44524]]: There is more than one data    
source column with the name "Encounter Number".  The data source column names must be 
unique.

(Microsoft Visual Studio)


===================================

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0207015 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.CManagedComponentWrapperClass.
ReinitializeMetaData()
at 
Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.
DataFlowComponentUI.ReinitializeMetadata()
at 
Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.FlatFileDestinationUI.conn
Page_SaveConnectionAttributes(Object sender, FlatFileConnectionAttributesEventArgs   
args)
```

Is there an error output or some other way of handling the duplicate Encounter field so that the fields can be mapped into my flat file destination?

Update:  Here's a screen shot of the data flow:
[image]

The metadata from the data conversion is as follows:

```
"Name"  "Data Type" "Precision" "Scale" "Length"    "Code Page"   
"Encounter Number"  "DT_STR"    "0" "0" "20"    "1252"  "0" ""    
"OLE DB Source"
"Encounter Number"  "DT_WSTR"   "0" "0" "20"    "0" "0" ""    
"Data Conversion"
```

How do I remove the Data Conversion or OLE DB Source version of the Encounter Number?  Is this a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it shouldn't be that difficult to find the two queries that both have Encounter as a column name and change one of them to return a different column name.

Comment: Hi Edmund, Thanks for your reply.  I've updated my posting with a screenshot and metadata from the Data Conversion output.  Can elaborate further as to how I would change one of the fields to ensure it doesn't get added twice?

Comment: Is the Data Conversion transform the one creating the second Encounter field? If so, it's trivially easy to rename the field that the transform creates, and you can manually update the mappings in the Flat File destination as needed to get the right field in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two columns with the same name in the source file,you can change that in connection manager, for instance if your source file is text or csv then in flat file connection manager, In the advance tab you can change the name of the column and load the data. This will work if you had same column name for two different columns in the source file.

Comment: This worked well, thanks. Before this I was just deleting the column from the file connection manager which resulted in extra information being grouped in the wrong column.